# Grid not updating when updating viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a grid with a list of servers, when the window is opened, I request a list of servers and than update the viewmodel. But the changes are not shown in my viewmodel.

```
public ServerInfo_ViewModel serverInfoViewModel { get; set; }

public FindServer2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(WindowLoaded);
    serverInfoViewModel = new ServerInfo_ViewModel();
}

void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Multicast.OnAlarmServerFound += new Multicast.AlarmServerFoundHandler(Multicast_OnAlarmServerFound);
     Multicast.FindAlarmServers();
}

public delegate void Multicast_OnAlarmServerFoundHandler(string IPAddress, string returnvalue);
    void Multicast_OnAlarmServerFound(string IPAddress, string returnvalue)
    {

         ServerInfo si = new ServerInfo();
         si.Server = IPAddress;

         if (source.Length > 1)
              si.Version = source[1];
         if (source.Length > 2)
              si.Connection = source[2];
         if (source.Length > 3)
              si.Port = source[3];
         if (source.Length > 4)
              si.HostName = source[4];
         if (source.Length > 1)
         {
            try
            {
               serverInfoViewModel.Servers.Add(si);   // This is called
            }
            catch
            {}
        }
    }
```

This is my viewmodel

```
    public class ServerInfo_ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ServerInfo_ViewModel()
        {
            this.Servers = new ObservableCollection<ServerInfo>();
            LoadInitialServerList();
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ServerInfo> Servers
        {
            get 
            {
                return servers;
            }
            set
            {
                servers = value;
                servers.CollectionChanged += new System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler(servers_CollectionChanged); 
            }
        }

        void servers_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Here you will be informed, if the content of the collection has been changed.  
            OnPropertyChanged("Servers");
        }

        private ObservableCollection<ServerInfo> servers;

        private void LoadInitialServerList()
        {
            servers.Add(new ServerInfo("Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test"));
        }

        #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

And Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Digicom.DESDigitelClientWPF.FindServer2"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Digicom.DESDigitelClientWPF"
>

<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ServerInfo_ViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>

<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Servers, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="132" Width="442" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="None">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding HostName}" Header="Server"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Server}" Header="IP" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Version}" Header="Version" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Connection}" Header="Connection" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Port}" Header="Port" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

When I run it I get this, the initial object is shown, but not the second that was added at runtime.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the Datacontext Definition from your XAML file and add it in the Codebehind.
Your code creates two instances of the ViewModel. You have added the ServerInfo to the instance that isn't bound to the View an therefore couldn't see the change.

ViewModel

```
public class ServerInfo_ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ServerInfo_ViewModel()
    {
        this.Servers = new ObservableCollection<ServerInfo>();
        LoadInitialServerList();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<ServerInfo> Servers
    {
        get 
        {
            return servers;
        }
        set
        {
            if(servers != value)
            {
                servers = value; 
                OnPropertyChanged("Servers");
            }
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<ServerInfo> servers;

    private void LoadInitialServerList()
    {
        servers.Add(new ServerInfo("Test", "Test", "Test", "Test", "Test"));
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="Digicom.DESDigitelClientWPF.FindServer2"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Digicom.DESDigitelClientWPF"
>
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Servers, Mode=TwoWay}" Height="132" Width="442" AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLinesVisibility="None">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding HostName}" Header="Server"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Server}" Header="IP" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Version}" Header="Version" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Connection}" Header="Connection" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Port}" Header="Port" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
</StackPanel>
```

Codebehind:

```
public ServerInfo_ViewModel serverInfoViewModel { get; set; }

public FindServer2()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(WindowLoaded);
    serverInfoViewModel = new ServerInfo_ViewModel();
    this.DataContext = serverInfoViewModel;

}

void WindowLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Multicast.OnAlarmServerFound += new Multicast.AlarmServerFoundHandler(Multicast_OnAlarmServerFound);
     Multicast.FindAlarmServers();
}

public delegate void Multicast_OnAlarmServerFoundHandler(string IPAddress, string returnvalue);
    void Multicast_OnAlarmServerFound(string IPAddress, string returnvalue)
    {

         ServerInfo si = new ServerInfo();
         si.Server = IPAddress;

         if (source.Length > 1)
              si.Version = source[1];
         if (source.Length > 2)
              si.Connection = source[2];
         if (source.Length > 3)
              si.Port = source[3];
         if (source.Length > 4)
              si.HostName = source[4];
         if (source.Length > 1)
         {
            try
            {
               serverInfoViewModel.Servers.Add(si);   // This is called
            }
            catch
            {}
        }
    }
```